# Problem with armature with automatic weight

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I am relatively new to blender and was following this [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0fEx02iXR8uhDsVGhmM9Pse&index=4&ab_channel=SebastianLague), everything was going well and my IK were working on the bones, but, when I tried to parent the bones to the mesh everything went chaotic. I have tried subsurf and mirroring but I might have done something wrong. Here's the before 
[image: Before]

---

and the after
[image]

I don't know if I can upload files (if I can please tell me) but I would preffer to know why it doesn't work, anyways here's the [.BLEND file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/swabl37wm2aoe9e/Character.blend/file) on Mediafire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If automatic weight doesn't work, you need to adjust the weight paint of the bones manually https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9S-jhBIEiU

Comment: Thanks, after a bit of experimenting with weight maps it started showing results.